# Default views for list folders isn't working in new experience lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-views

I'm trying to set up a folder based list where the top level of the list will only contain folders of a custom type "Incident" and the incident folders will contain other types such as "Action" etc.

I have this set up but the automatic view selection isn't working.  I have created two views:

- Incidents - set to show in "Top-level" and is set as the default view
- Actions - set to show in folders of type "Incident" and is also set as the default view

I want it to automatically switch between those views when I go from the top level to the "Incident" level but it doesn't.  It just stays at whatever I last set it to and both views are available in both the top level folder and the incident folders.

Our site is configured to use the "new experience" and if I change the list to use the "classic experience" instead of the default one then this part works.

I don't want to use the classic experience because other parts of it don't work well for what we want and also we need to be able to use the list from Teams which seems to use the new experience regardless of the setting in the list.

Is there something that I am doing wrong or is it a fault in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure Per-location view settings in the library?

If so, then I am afraid that the Per-location view settings only can work for classic experience. It cannot work for modern experience.

You can see the views based on locations by clicking the folders from the tree view only. These views will not show when you click the items in the library view on the main part of the page.

The modern experience is the new feature. And it will be improved in the future.

More reference:

[Per-location view settings don't work at the folder level in SharePoint 2013, SharePoint 2010, and SharePoint Online.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/support/lists-and-libraries/per-location-view-settings-fail-working)

Comment: No, I set up custom folder default views as per section 4 of this page: https://camerondwyer.com/2014/01/06/harness-sharepoint-default-views-at-different-navigation-hierarchy-levels-to-build-more-appealing-solutions/ It's got the same effect as the per-location view settings but you define it by content type, not  by location.  I guess that it just doesn't work yet for the new experience and that they'll fix it when they fix it.  It's frustrating though as it would be perfect for our needs if it worked.